# Yeoman cannot install MEAN.js template

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, windows-10, meanjs

I am using Windows 10.  When I try to install the MEAN.js template in Yeoman I get the following error:

```
C:\My_Path>yo meanjs
undefined
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? (Use arrow keys)
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.0
0.4.0
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. mean
Cloning the MEAN repo.......
Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "rm ./mean/package.json
"
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

F:\>yo --version
1.5.0

F:\>npm --version
3.3.12
```

Comment: Your work around is at the end of this list on github: https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/118